# How to debug a groovy based plugin and step into its source with IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy, gradle-plugin

I have custom gradle (Groovy) plugin as a separate project. My project that uses the plugin downloads the plugin from nexus repo where it I publish it myself.

Now when I debug some task in my project with IntelliJ, stepping into the plugin code leads to compile Java code instead of original Groovy source of the plugin. How do I debug gradle plugin with IntelliJ in a way I can step into it’s groovy source while debugging?

Comment: is the src jar published to your nexus?

Comment: @tim_yates My understanding is that even if I publish source jar, it still won't work because source is groovy. Instead of source jar, when IntelliJ asked about source, I pointed it to the actually source directory of plugin project and it didn't work properly.

Comment: Does it help to add your plugin's code as a module dependency? LIke that: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-module-dependencies.html